# How create custom EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want create custom EditText. It should look like this
[image]

I crete this, but i can not create vertical  line. My EditText:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/paymentCode"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blue_card"/>
```

It looks like this

[image]

Comment: Hey to remove cursor from edittext use this to xml file in edittext.
android:cursorVisible="false"

Comment: set  `android:cursorVisible="true"` and `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`

Comment: Check out this : https://github.com/dbachelder/CreditCardEntry

Comment: this is not the cursor. I wrote. This separator and must be added

Answer (score 0):

**First Check this out**

https://github.com/faradaj/PatternedEditText

**Picture**
[image: githubview]

**Secondly**

You need to extend Edittext in a new java class and apply your custom design in it.
here are some examples
(ofcourse its not the whole thing you want but already i have told you have to make your own view by yourself)

https://alinberce.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/android-edittext-with-custom-font-and-clear-button/

http://www.programering.com/a/MzNyITMwATY.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/524556/Android-customize-EditText-like-a-page-in-textbook